# Is there any way to compose mail in gmail through selenium automation?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using selenium IDE neon 3.0 and I am trying to automate gmail through webdriver. When I tried to compose a mail after clicking to it, it shows element not found.

Here is my selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='to']"));
Compose_mail.to().sendKeys("sender");
driver.findElement(By.name("subject"));
Compose_mail.sub().sendKeys("subject");
```

Comment: You should consider using the GMail API directly, rather than having to go through the UI. Eg you could use the Python gmail API and call into that from selenium. That will be a more stable and supported interface for programmatic use. Or perhaps you could share in the question why you have some important reason not to use this approach.

Comment: Adam Burke  im doing the coding in java, and i wanted to try through UI only its my project facing the same issue when i tried through xpath, cssSelector, by.id, by.name every time it says element not found. stuck here and even i tried through commonmail API also there i got authenticationError